# Unexpected string in JSON while parsing XML

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, rest

I am trying to read the clob which is basically XML from Oracle DB and populate in AngularJS UI Grid.
I am doing the same with JSON and is working perfectly fine.

**JSON response from backend**

```
{"events":{"ORDER_NO":"BBY01-100000709660","ORDER_HEADER_KEY":"2020040811522311790606  ","CREATETS":"2020-04-08 11:52:47","TMPLT_NM":"EOMS_0194                               ","EMAIL_XML":"<email CommunicationType=\"Email\" SourceSystem=\"OMS\" TemplatePageZone=\"\" brand=\"BESTBUY\" channel=\"BESTBUY\" emailAddr=\"test.tester@bestbuy.com\" template=\"EOMS_0178_TEST\">""    <name firstName=\"Test\" lastName=\"\" middleInitial=\"\"/>""    <order ATGID=\"ATG28268080246\" IsSuppressRequired=\"Y\" LoggedInFlag=\"Y\" LoyaltyID=\"0160140134\" OrderName=\"MSFTAllAccess\" PartyID=\"123456\" PriorityNumber=\"160140134\" customerPhoneNo=\"6515554321\" hasActivatedDevice=\"N\" orderDate=\"01/28/2020\" orderHeaderKey=\"2020012813423582265743\" orderIdATG=\"BBY01-1MT2010012802\" orderStatusLinkDisplayFlag=\"Y\" orderTotal=\"0.00\" orderTotalMinusCoupons=\"0.00\" partnerID=\"\" partnerOrderNo=\"MAV513281qweq1\" salesSource=\"BBYC\" shippingTotal=\"0.00\" taxTotal=\"0.00\">""        <creditCard cardType=\"\" number=\"\"/>""        <digitalCoupons digitalCouponTotal=\"0.00\"/>""        <lineItems>""            <lineItem CustPromiseDate=\"02/26/2020\" CustPromiseType=\"InHandDate\" availabilityMsg=\"\" beginEstArrivalDate=\"02/24/2020\" conditionVariableOne=\"\" conditionVariableTwo=\"\" description=\"Microsoft  Surface Pro 3  12  Intel Core i7  256GB  Silver\" endEstArrivalDate=\"02/26/2020\" expectedShipDays=\"\" format=\"\" giftPackaging=\"N\" inHandDate=\"02/26/2020\" itemID=\"\" itemShortDesc=\"Microsoft  Surface Pro 3  12  Intel Core i7  256GB  Silver\" lineItemProductTotal=\"0.00\" lineItemShippingCost=\"0.00\" merchClass=\"\" modelNo=\"1000186097\" orderLineKey=\"2020021911334791500160\" oversizeFlag=\"\" pickupDate=\"\" preOrder=\"\" primeLine=\"1\" productLine=\"6.403.635\" quantity=\"1\" releaseDate=\"\" reshipReasonCode=\"RESHIP_DAMAGED_ITEM\" shipDate=\"\" shippingMethod=\"\" signatureRequiredFlag=\"N\" sku=\"9248206\" status=\"\" subLine=\"1\" tax=\"0.00\" total=\"0.00\" unitPrice=\"0.00\" unitShippingCost=\"0.00\">""                <shippingAddr city=\"RICHFIELD\" line1=\"1000 W 78TH ST\" line2=\"\" state=\"MN\" zip=\"55423\">""                    <name firstName=\"Test\" lastName=\"Tester\" middleInitial=\"\"/>""                </shippingAddr>""                <allowance allowanceAmt=\"0.00\" reason=\"\"/>""                <return date=\"\" lineQty=\"\" lineTotal=\"0.00\" productCredit=\"0.00\" reason=\"\" restockingFee=\"0.00\" shippingCredit=\"0.00\" taxCredit=\"0.00\"/>""                <cancel backOrderExtendedXNumDays=\"\" reason=\"\"/>""                <ros actualDeliveryDate=\"\" pickupDate=\"\"/>""                <store storeName=\"\" storeNum=\"\"/>""                <psp plan=\"\"/>""                <carriers>""                    <carrier los=\"\" name=\"\" quantity=\"\" trackingNum=\"\"/>""                </carriers>""            </lineItem>""        </lineItems>""        <makeGood makeGoodFlag=\"N\"/>""    </order>""    <account atgProfileId=\"\" cirisID=\"\" info=\"\" password=\"\"/>""    <comments/>""</email>"}}
```

Whenever i am trying to read the values it is throwing exception

> Unexpected string in JSON at position 372
>       at JSON.parse (`<anonymous>`)

Below is the AJAX response code:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    if(response.data.events == null || response.data.events == undefined ||
            response.data.events == "undefined"){
        $("#loader1").hide();
        $scope.close = true;
        $scope.responseMessage = "";
        $scope.gridOptions1.data.length=0;
        $scope.errorMessage = "Order not found!!!!";
    }else{
        console.log("1");
        $("#loader1").hide();
        var responseNew = JSON.stringify(response.data.events);
        $scope.gridOptions1.data = responseNew;
        $scope.mySelectedRows = $scope.gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        $scope.close = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.responseMessage = "Order details fetched successfully";
    }
}, function(response) {
    $("#loader1").hide();
    $scope.close = true;
    $scope.responseMessage = "";
    $scope.gridOptions.data.length=0;
    $scope.gridOptions1.data.length=0;
});
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Use any online JSON validator to see for yourself, e.g. https://jsonlint.com/. --- E.g. look out at the end: `<comments/>""</email>"}}`. That `""` is bad and seems to be where a line terminator was supposed to be in the JSON literal. Replace all `""` with `\n` (the two characters ``\`` and `n`, not a linefeed character), and you might be able to fix the JSON so it can be parsed.

Comment: The same when i am trying to get for JSON then i am able to parse. Please see the JSON below:
`{"events":[{"ORDER_NO":"BBY01-100000709660","ORDER_HEADER_KEY":"2020040811522311790606  ","EVNT_NM":"ORDER_CONFIRMATION_EVENT","RVSN_NO":"1                       ","CREATETS":"2020-04-08 11:52:47","EVNT_JSON":"{\"catalog\":\"BBY\",\"created\":\"2020-04-08T11:52:36-05:00\",\"modified\":\"2020-04-08T11:52:36-05:00\",\"submitted\":\"2020-04-08T11:52:19-05:00\",\"userOrderId\":\"BBY01-100000709660\",\"revision\":1,\"purchaseOrderNumber\":\"\"}]}`

Comment: Don't (attempt to) post full JSON in a comment. Edit the question if you have clarifying information.

Comment: @brainSquezer the json attached in question is not valid as double quote is not properly escaped.

Comment: The above issue got fixed but now i am getting below error:
newRawData.forEach is not a function
    at Grid.modifyRows

Comment: Don't ask a completely new question in the commends. If this is fixed, answer / close / delete or do something to this, and post a new question.

Comment: i have asked new question in the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122543/angularui-grid-is-not-population-data

Answer (score 0):

There's one double quote extra here:

```
Parse error on line 1:
...\"EOMS_0178_TEST\">""    <name firstName...
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify. The response you're getting from back-end (the one you mentioned above)  is already a stringified JSON, you have to parse it out to read the values.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue waswhile storing the xml in DB. since the new elements had spaces in between. it was considering that as a string and was getting appended with double quotes in JSON.